# Ajax call works only first time

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

This is my code, to modify the content of a table cell, clicking a link "Open/Close" of the sibling cell.

The link works good the first time but on the second click, the execution start again from

```
$("a[href*='close']").click(function (event)
```

even if the new link contains "open" and not the word "close" anymore.

Why have I this behaviour?
Which is the problem? How can I solve it?

Thanks in advance!

```
$(document).ready(function()
    {

        $("a[href*='close']").click(function (event)
        {
            event.preventDefault();
            var click = $(this);
            console.log(click);
            var url = click.attr("href");
            console.log(url);
            var nid = url.split("/")[1];
            console.log(nid);
            // var url = "close/" + nid;
            // console.log(url);
            $.get(url, function(data, status)
            {
                if (data.status == 1)
                {
                    console.log(data.res);
                    click.text("Open");
                    var new_url = url.replace("close", "open");
                    console.log("New Url = " + new_url);
                    click.attr("href", new_url);
                    click.parent().prev().text(data.res);
                }
                else
                {
                    console.log("Error");
                }

            });
        });        // CHIUDE FUNZIONE

        $("a[href*='open']").click(function (event)
        {
            event.preventDefault();
            var click2 = $(this);
            console.log(click2);
            var url = click2.attr("href");
            console.log(url);
            var nid = url.split("/")[1];
            console.log(nid);
            // var url = "open/" + nid;
            // console.log(url);
            $.get(url, function(data, status)
            {
                if (data.status == 1)
                {
                    console.log(data.res);
                    click2.text("Close");
                    var new_url = url.replace("open", "close");
                    console.log("New Url = " + new_url);
                    click2.attr("href", new_url);
                    click2.parent().prev().text(data.res);
                }
                else
                {
                    console.log("Error");
                }

            });
        });        // CHIUDE FUNZIONE
```

Comment: Events are bound to elements.  Once they are bound, they are there until they are removed.  And the only thing that removes event bindings from an element is the logic taking them off, or the element being destroyed.  No other change to the element removes bindings.  As such, you are replacing the open/close on the link, but the original binding put on it will still exist.  One easy way to solve this is to use a delegate binding, rather than a direct binding.  A delegate binding evaluates its child selector for every event that bubbles up to it.  So it **is** reactive to an elements state.

Comment: Find a parent element to the anchor and bind to that using `$(<parent>).on('click', 'a[href*="close"]', function(event){...})`

Comment: Everything went fine, thanks a lot for you fast answer and overall really clear example, what I didn't find in any other place. 
Have fun guys, you made my day! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I stated in my comment to the question, you can use a delegate event binding, rather than juggling event bindings, to allow events to only be processed by the logic that you want them to be processed by.

```js
$(document).on('click', 'a[href*="close"]', function (event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  console.log('close');
  event.target.href = '#open';
});

$(document).on('click', 'a[href*="open"]', function (event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  console.log('open');
  event.target.href = '#close';
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="#open">Toggle</a>
```